# How to bind to ready event on socket.io?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I have the following express/socket.io application:

```
var express = require('express');
var sio = require('socket.io');

var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app).listen(3000, function () {
   console.log('Server listening on 3000 port');
});

var io = sio.listen(server);
```

As you can see from the code above we listen to 3000 port and pring `Server listening on 3000 port` message to console. Now I need to print same message for socket.io listen method but this method one does't get callback. So I need something like the following:

```
var io = sio.listen(server);
io.on('ready', function () {
     console.log('Socket io server listening...');
});
```

How could I bind to listen event for socket.io?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a concise way:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = app.listen(3000);
var io      = require('socket.io')(server);

server.on('listening', function() {
  console.log('Server listening on 3000 port');
});
```

This way, `socket.io` will piggyback on top of Express, and when the `listening` event fires, `socket.io` is ready too.

If you want, you can replace the `listening` event handler by passing it as a callback to `app.listen()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it a bit wrong. If you init express app and socket.io like this

```
httpServer = http.createServer( app ).listen( process.env.PORT, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0", function() { 
    console.log( "Express app initialized" );
    var io = require( 'socket.io' )( httpServer );
});
```

it will call `attach` method of socket.io which indeed does not have a callback.

What you could do is check `io` variable later, it should not be null. Or even better wrap it in `try/catch` like this

```
var io, httpServer;
httpServer = http.createServer( app ).listen( process.env.PORT, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0", function() { 
    console.log( "Express app initialized" );
    try {
        io = require( 'socket.io' )( httpServer );
        if( io != null ) {
            console.log( "Socket server ready!" )
            // do what is needed later
        }
        else {
            throw new Error( "Returned null after attaching to express server." );
        }
    }
    catch( error ) {
        console.log( "Failed to init socket.io!", error );
    }

});
```